# Get-Content source codepage?

Tags: powershell, internationalization

I have a plain text .txt file encoded with Windows codepage 1250. I need to read the file on an English/Western Europe Windows system which uses codepage 1252.

The Get-Content `-Encoding` parameter expects a text string from a fixed set which does not include other codepages.

I can use GetEncoding(), but this result cannot be used as the -Encoding parameter to Get-Content.

How can I tell `Get-Content` to read the file using 1250 encoding?

```
PS C:\src\t> [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('windows-1250')


IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-2
EncodingName      : Central European (Windows)
HeaderName        : windows-1250
WebName           : windows-1250
WindowsCodePage   : 1250
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1250
```

Comment: have you tried running `chcp 1250` before Get-Content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell Get-Content to read the file using 1250 encoding?

I'm afraid you can't. `Get-Content` expects to be given one of the [`FileSystemCmdletProviderEncoding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.filesystemcmdletproviderencoding?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) enum values, and they are not fine-grained enough. But you can easily use the native .NET facilities to read the file.

```
$windows1250 = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('windows-1250')
$path = ".\path\to\your\file.txt"
$text = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path, $windows1250)
```

Comment: This looks like it will work. Does `Get-Content` provide things like pipeline buffering that the raw `[System.Io.File]` methods do not? Is there a reason that `Get-Content` cannot specify a [System.Text.Encoding]`?

Comment: I have no idea why regular `System.Text.Encoding` instances are not accepted, looks like a design flaw to me. Yes, you will lose pipeline buffering with the `System.IO.File`, which means you should probably not use this with gigabyte-size text files. A small PowerShell function with `[CmdletBinding]` that internally uses `System.IO.StreamReader` can overcome this.

Comment: Basically like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time, only transliterated to PowerShell code.